# ImportError Exception Value: No module named urls Exception Location: /home/pradeep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

https://tests4geeks.com/django-rest-framework-tutorial/

Above Tutorial URL I am following for djangorestframework API implementatuion My admin site is working perfectly, I can add Student and Universities successfully and after that while I moved to "**Django REST framework-based api**" steps I did same as given still getting error.

Can anybody suggest what to do for fix.

Comment: Have you created any virtual environment ? If yes did you activate it ?

Comment: Please add relevant snippets of your code, and the entire stack trace of the error

Comment: can you check "pip install djangorestframework" installed properly?

Comment: virtual enviornment is created and activated.

Comment: Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 119, in get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 365, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 401, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 395, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)

Comment: Add it to your question.